# Html database connectivity and fetching the data

Tags: html

i have to create one html news letter template and i have to fetch the data for news letter 
template from database so how to pull data from database dynamically into a html news letter template

pls help me on this
actually i am trying this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> NO TITTLE   </title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";

$myDB = "STrack"; 


$dbhandle = mssql_connect( $myServer , $myUser)
  or die( "Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 


$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 


$query = "SELECT Name, Password, Company FROM users WHERE Name='Admin' ";



$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 


while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["Name"] . $row["Password"] . $row["Company"] . "</li>";
}

$mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks & Regards
Aditya Kashyap.

Comment: This question is too broad and doesn't demonstrate any effort on your part to solve the problem.  Please read the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before asking members to help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

create a database to store email address and also whether a user receiving it for first time or not then create a html content(lets call it $content) in php and use mail function

e.g:

```
mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
```

then update your database

Comment: also don't forget to add $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;